# People crossing a bridge (a proof for a greedy algorithm)

Tags: proof-techniques, correctness-proof, greedy-algorithms

**The problem**

Some people are crossing a bridge. Each one takes a different time to pass.

Assume the people are sorted by their passing time increasingly.

These are the conditions of crossing the bridge:

1. only 1 or 2 people can cross the bridge at the same time in the same direction;
2. the speed of the two people crossing is the same as the slower one;
3. it is night and there is only one flashlight;
4. the people passing the bridge must carry the flashlight;
5. the flashlight cannot be thrown over the bridge so it must be carried back to the other end of the bridge.

**My greedy solution**

The obvious solution seems to be using the fastest guy to take every one to the other end and come back for the rest.

**The proof**

I tried to prove it like my text book CLRS:

> 1. Cast the optimization problem as one in which we make a choice and are
>      left with one subproblem to solve.
> 2. Prove that there is always an optimal solution to the original problem
>      that makes the greedy choice, so that the greedy choice is always
>      safe.
> 3. Demonstrate optimal substructure by showing that, having made the greedy choice, what remains is a subproblem with the property that if
>      we combine an optimal solution to the subproblem with the greedy
>      choice we have made, we arrive at an optimal solution to the original
>      problem.

I tried something like this:

If we assume the set of all people in the start is $P$ and the set of all people in the destination is $D$ and $O(x)$ is the function that gives the optimum time by getting the set of people and people $p_i$ and $p_j$ are chosen to pass the bridge and $d_k$ is chosen to return the light and $d_k \in D\cup \{p_i , p_j\}$ then:

$$O(P) = Max( t(p_i) , t(p_j) ) + t(d_k) + O(P-\{p_i , p_j\} \cup {d_k})\,,$$

where $t(p_i)$ is the time it takes for person $p_i$ to pass.

Now I have to assume I have an optimal solution $OS$ and show that I can use the greedy choice instead of the choice the $OS$ has made.

I do not know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't prove that the greedy algorithm is correct is because it isn't.

Suppose the people cross the bridge in times 1, 2, 5 and 10 minutes.  The greedy solution involves the one-minute person walking backwards and forwards every time and takes 10+1+5+1+2=19 minutes.  The optimal solution is 17 minutes (spoiler, since it's a famous puzzle that people might want to try on their own).

> 1 and 2 cross, 2 returns with the flashlight, then 5 and 10 cross and 1 returns with the flashlight to collect 2: total time 2+2+10+1+2=17 minutes.

Comment: does there a correct greedy measure exist

Comment: what about using dynamic programming

Comment: I don't see how dynamic programming would work, since there's no obvious decomposition into sub-problems. I'd try some sort of search algorithm; A* if you can come up with an appropriate heuristic.

Comment: No need for A*. There is a relatively simple (but tricky) greedy strategy to this classic problem. See "Crossing the Bridge at Night" by G.Rothe.
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Guenter_Rote/publication/220530399_Crossing_the_Bridge_at_Night/links/0912f50eefbeaa338b000000/Crossing-the-Bridge-at-Night.pdf.